# Strided convolution & residual connection

Tags: deep-learning

I am studying **SwishNet**, a Fast CNN for Speech, Music and Noise Classification and Segmentation.

In that [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00149), they used **Strided Convolution** & **Residual Net**. After through `stride=2 conv layer` its output length will be half of the input length.

My question is how can merger output with input(residual connection) even their array dimension is mismatched?

**G.A** is just gated activation function, so it does not affect on the output dimension!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the reference paper [Conditional Image Generation with
PixelCNN Decoders](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05328.pdf) which Gate Activation (**G.A**) borrowed from, you can notice that it use the following formula:

[image: G.A formula]

Although `stride=2` reduce dimension to half of the input size, **G.A** layer with proper `W` dimension produce the same as the input dimension which means no mismatch dimension will occur.